# Recursive Lists

Tags: haskell, recursion, functional-programming, tail-recursion

I would like to create an infinite list as follows

```
(1:[]):(2:2:[]):(3:3:3:[]) ...
```

I have tried a lot and the best I can think of is

```
function = (1:[]) : map ( \n -> n ) (  from 2 )
```

I am sure that this need to be done recursively but I cant see it

any tips or help would be great thanks

Answer (score 3):

How about this one:

```
concatMap (\x -> replicate x x) [1..]
```

It has no explicit recursion but does what you want.

As Keshav Kini points out you probably want the version without concatenation:

```
map (\x -> replicate x x) [1..]
```

Comment: I think you mean just `map (\x -> replicate x x) [1..]`, no?

Comment: Just for fun, note that `(\x -> replicate x x)` is simply `join replicate`, so you could write this as `map (join replicate) [1..]`; or, shorter still, as `join replicate <$> [1..]`.

Comment: To use applicative notation, you can also use ``map (replicate <*> id) [1..]``, which emphasises the number of replications.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proposal for a recursive definition:

`lss = [1]:map (\ls -> (1+head ls):(map (+1) ls)) lss`

(even though the replicate solution is shorter!)